# Replace [keyword] in post_content with words from post_title MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm on a bit of a rampage today as I have been trying to literally weeks to get my website fully functional.

I have 500 posts or so with the heading "best hotel deals in XXXXX" and I have a template in each post_content row in the table.

Inside the template are words like [keyword], and I want to replace the "[keyword]" with "XXX" from the title.

Is this possible?

So, for example:

"post_title = Best hotel deals in London"

post_content = We have the best hotel deals in [keyword]"

I want to replace [keyword], with London." within the post_content.

I also have some search criteria for the certain posts I want to be affected, and they are the following:

```
SELECT *
```

FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_title` LIKE 'best hotel deals in%'
AND `post_status` LIKE 'draft'

Any suggestions?

Comment: @aggressionexp, I am a complete amateur with sql, so I dont know how to use php regex, however, I do have a list of all the keywords separately on CSV, if that helps.

Comment: Really need some help with this, is there any way this can be done? or anyone know of any plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this:

```
    update wp_posts
set post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'[keyword]',trim(SUBSTR(post_title, 21))) 
where post_title like 'best hotel deals in%' and post_status = 'draft'`
```

Worked like a dream.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

- first, you need to extract the title keyword from post_title using [php regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with pattern like '**/best hotel deals in (.+?)$/i**' use $ if title keyword goes to the end of line.
- and then, you use php [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace [keyword] with your keyword found in the first step

as for your search criteria question, I don't understand your question, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the update for a single keyword in SQL like this:

```
update
    wp_posts
set
    post_content = 
        concat(
            substr(post_content, 1, instr(post_content, '[Keyword]') - 1),
            substr(post_title, instr(post_title, 'Best hotel deals in ') + 20),
            substr(post_content, instr(post_content, '[Keyword]') + 9)
        )
where
    post_title like 'best hotel deals in%' and
    post_status = 'draft' and
    post_content like '%\\[keyword\\]%'
```

Note, however, that if you're dealing with multiple keywords, this is going to get messy in a hurry.  You are much better off using WordPress' built-in templating tools, or one of the many available WordPress plug-ins, rather than doing extensive manipulation directly in the database.  Square peg, round hole, and all of that.

Comment: hi jokeeffe, the only keywords I have is [keyword], I just have it multiple times. or do you mean if after "best hotel deals in " there are 2 keywords, such as "north london", it could get messy?

Comment: When you mentioned you had a list of keywords in a CSV file, that's what made me think you were looking to replace multiple keywords.  The technique above will work for something like "North London".  The area where I thought you might have problems would be if you wanted to do replacements like "Best [DealType] in [Localtion]" -- writing a generic template mechanism like that is probably not something that you want to do in SQL.

Comment: I used the query above, I had to change the capital letter in "[Keyword]" to apply it correctly, but it only affected 1 "[keyword]", I have 6 "[keyword]" to replace in the content.